# How do I get series data to display in bar chart legend

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, bar-chart, legend

I have a Windows Forms Application that displays a graph from data stored in a database. I am able to get the data to display in a bar graph or pie graph. But the legend in the bar graph only displays "Series1", the name of the series. The legend of the pie chart displays a correct legend with the series data. I've searched MSDN and found several articles on adding a legend but they all have the same results.

Here is my bar chart code:

```
        string[] xvals = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        int[] yvals = new int[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            xvals[i] = dt.Rows[i]["XValues"].ToString();
            yvals[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["YValues"].ToString());
        }

        Chart barChart = new Chart();
        ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
        barChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
        barChart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        barChart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        barChart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Fire;
        barChart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        barChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        barChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

        Series series1 = new Series
        { Name = "Series1", IsVisibleInLegend = true, ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar };
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

        barChart.Series.Add(series1);
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            series1.Points.AddXY(dt.Rows[i]["XValues"].ToString(),
                Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["YValues"].ToString()));
            var p1 = series1.Points[i];
            p1.Color = Color.FromArgb((byte)r.Next(90, 255), (byte)r.Next(90, 255), 160);
        }

        barChart.Legends.Add(new Legend("Legend1"));
        barChart.Legends["Legend1"].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        barChart.Series["Series1"].Legend = "Legend1";
        series1.IsVisibleInLegend = true;

        gbo1.Controls.Add(barChart);
```

Here is my pie chart code:

```
            string[] xvals = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        int[] yvals = new int[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            xvals[i] = dt.Rows[i]["XValues"].ToString();
            yvals[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["YValues"].ToString());
        }

        Chart pieChart = new Chart();
        ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
        chartArea.Name = "PieChartArea";
        pieChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
        pieChart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pieChart.Location = new Point(0, 50);

        pieChart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Fire;
        pieChart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pieChart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        Series series2 = new Series
        { Name = "Series2", IsVisibleInLegend = true, ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie };

        pieChart.Series.Add(series2);
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            series2.Points.Add((int)dt.Rows[i]["YValues"]);
            var p2 = series2.Points[i];
            p2.Color = Color.FromArgb((byte)r.Next(90, 255), (byte)r.Next(90, 255), 160);
            p2.LegendText = dt.Rows[i]["XValues"].ToString();
        }

        pieChart.Legends.Add(new Legend("Legend2"));
        pieChart.Legends["Legend2"].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pieChart.Series["Series2"].Legend = "Legend2";
        series2.IsVisibleInLegend = true;

        gboReport1.Controls.Add(pieChart);
```

What am I missing? Please help.

Here is the output of the bar chart:
[Bar Chart with bad Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOgwu.png)

Here is the output of the pie chart:
[Pie Chart with good Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoXZA.png)

Comment: Which chart api are you using?

Comment: Is this what you mean: using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

Answer (score 1):

That is how `Bar` and `Pie` charts are **designed** to work.

All `ChartTypes` **except** `Pie` charts display the `Series.Names` or  the `SeriesTexts` in their `Legend`.

Only `Pie` charts, which only have **one** `Series` anyway will display the `DataPoint.YValues[0]`.

If you really want to display datapoint data in your `Legend` you can do that, but of course it will look crowded if you add more than a few data points..

This is an example of how you can add hide the regular `Legend` and add a new one which displays the data values:

```
chart1.ApplyPaletteColors();
chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;

Legend L2 = new Legend();
chart1.Legends.Add(L2);
L2.Docking = Docking.Right;
foreach (DataPoint dp in yourSeries.Points)
{
    LegendItem LI = new LegendItem(dp.YValues[0].ToString("0.##"), dp.Color, "");
    LI.BorderWidth = 0;
    L2.CustomItems.Add(LI);
}
```

[image]

If you want to you can also add those items to the regular `Legend`; simply create a reference to it and use the code above:

```
Legend L1 = chart1.Legends[0];
```

Note that you can't delete the original items from the original `Legend`, though!