# Change Label Color in a Chart Control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, legend

The question I have seems to be simple but I can't find an answer around the Internet for that and even trying around did not help me.

I just want to change the color of a Legend (from a Series). I know how to change the text color but I need to change the color of that marker.

```
 chart1.Legends["1"].ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
 chart1.Legends["1"].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

does not help

Is this possible?

Thank you!

EDIT:

[image]

I want to change the blue color to another. Hope this is more clear now.

Comment: You want hide legend?

Comment: I just want to hide the color. I only need the Text of the label to be displayed. Or change the color of the label. Not the text

Comment: Try get your legend using: chart1.Series["1"].Legend.ForeColor =Color.Transparent ;

Comment: No. I edited my question. Hope this is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The markers show the `ChartType` and the `Color` of all the `Series`.

Unfortunately the default `LegendItems` anre hidden and can't be changed, only expanded.

So your best bet, except avoiding the issue by picking a a different green, (if that is why you want to change the blue) would be to clear or disable the default `Legend` and create a new one from scratch.

For this you can style all sorts of things including setting MarkerStyles and also Bitmaps you create on the fly..

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614148/make-chart-legend-represent-two-colors/36619240?s=1|5.3190#36619240) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492383/how-do-i-get-series-data-to-display-in-bar-chart-legend/40573106?s=3|2.4098#40573106) are two examples that show you how to do it..

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791944/how-to-add-data-table-with-legend-keys-to-a-ms-chart-in-c/35795254?s=5|1.8605#35795254) is one with a rather extended custom `Legend`

Instead of creating a new Legend you can also hide the LegendItem for a Series

```
series1.IsVisibleInLegend = true;
```

and add a new one but it will be added at the end..

Here is an example of adding a  simple LegendItem:

```
void AddLegendItem(Legend L, Series s, Color mc)
{
    LegendItem lit = new LegendItem();

    lit.BorderColor = mc;
    lit.Color = mc;
    lit.SeriesName = s.Name;
    lit.Name = s.Name;
    L.CustomItems.Add(lit);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I just also found an easy answer. Just have to change the color of the series the label is bound to to transparent

Comment: Hm, well that will also hide the DataPoints, though. Do you use Markers to display the data instead? Also your question quite clearly ask for changing the legenditemmarker color blue to another!

Comment: No I'm just using Labels. But the color comes from the chart color.